# Is it possible to do a for loop with an empty list in Python/sqlite3

Tags: python, database, sqlite, tkinter

I want the user to be able to update values to the database but i want to function to work the same way even if the record doesnt exist in database yet. So i would like to combine INSERT and UPDATE. I was thinking of doing a for loop for the records in the database to see if the record exist and then do an IF statement to decide if i should INSERT or UPDATE. I guess this would work everytime but the first time. If no records exists in the database this doesnt seem to work and i guess thats because i = none when the database is empty.

Example:

```
        conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT *, oid FROM database")
        schemalaggning = c.fetchall()
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        for i in schemalaggning:
            if clicked1.get() and clicked2.get() and clicked10.get() in i:
                   myUPDATEfunction()
            else:
                   myINSERTfunction2()

How can i solve this problem?


My specific code:
        conn = sqlite3.connect("schemalaggning.db")
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT *, oid FROM schemalaggning")
        schemalaggning = c.fetchall()
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()


        for i in schemalaggning:
            if clicked1.get() and clicked2.get() and clicked10.get() in i:
                conn = sqlite3.connect("schemalaggning.db")
                c = conn.cursor()
                c.execute("""UPDATE schemalaggning SET
                    namn = :namn,
                    ar = :ar,
                    vecka = :vecka,
                    mandag = :mandag,
                    tisdag = :tisdag,
                    onsdag = :onsdag,
                    torsdag = :torsdag,
                    fredag = :fredag,
                    lordag = :lordag,
                    sondag = :sondag
                    
                    WHERE oid = :oid""",
                    {
                    "namn": clicked10.get(),
                    "ar": clicked1.get(),
                    "vecka": clicked2.get(),
                    "mandag": clicked3.get(),
                    "tisdag": clicked4.get(),
                    "onsdag": clicked5.get(),
                    "torsdag": clicked6.get(),
                    "fredag": clicked7.get(),
                    "lordag": clicked8.get(),
                    "sondag": clicked9.get(),
                    "oid": i[10]


                    })
                conn.commit()
                conn.close()
            else:
                pass
                conn = sqlite3.connect("schemalaggning.db")
                c = conn.cursor()
                c.execute("INSERT INTO schemalaggning VALUES (:namn, :ar, :vecka, :mandag, :tisdag, :onsdag, :torsdag, :fredag, :lordag, :sondag)",
                          {
                              
                              "namn": clicked10.get(),
                              "ar": clicked1.get(),
                              "vecka": clicked2.get(),
                              "mandag": clicked3.get(),
                              "tisdag": clicked4.get(),
                              "onsdag": clicked5.get(),
                              "torsdag": clicked6.get(),
                              "fredag": clicked7.get(),
                              "lordag": clicked8.get(),
                              "sondag": clicked9.get()

                          }
                          )
                conn.commit()
                conn.close()
```

Comment: Maybe just an [upsert](https://www.sqlite.org/draft/lang_UPSERT.html) would be adequate?

Comment: I havent heard of upsert before (im a beginner) and im not sure i understand from the link. Does it mean that the data will be inserted if record doesnt exist and updated if record exist? How would you write this using your upsert? I still need to know where to put the data if the record already exists so how do i write the code?

Comment: I think there's enough info there to explain it; you might look at other sources as well if that one isn't clear. I believe it can do exactly what you're asking for; as for how to apply it to your specific situation, it's hard to say without having the actual statements as a part of your example. For more detailed answers it could help to provide a [mre].

Comment: I have updated my post with my specific code.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem by adding this line before my for loop.

```
if len(schemalaggning) < 1:
    addfunction
else:
    for loop as above
```